# Can't navigate from header React Native Navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Hi I'm trying to navigate to a shopping cart from inside a products page called merchandise and I can't seem to navigate using the header. I've tried using options and screenoptions but both aren't working and I'm thinking I'm putting the navigation in the wrong place? I've loaded the shopping cart nav into the merch nav but I can't seem to navigate to this from the shopping cart icon component

MerchNav

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, SafeAreaView, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { useDimensions } from '@react-native-community/hooks';
import { createStackNavigator, HeaderStyleInterpolators } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import ArtistMerch from '../pages/ArtistPages/ArtistMerch';
import ShoppingCartNav from '../navigation/ShoppingCartNav'
import ShoppingCartIcon from '../components/ShoppingCartIcon';


const Stack = createStackNavigator();


export default function MerchNav() {
  console.log(useDimensions());

  return (
 
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name = {'ProductsList'} component={ArtistMerch} options={({navigation}) => ({headerStyle: {backgroundColor: 'lightblue'}, 
        headerTitle: (
          <View style={styles.logo}>
              <Text style={styles.logo}> Merchandise </Text>
          </View>),
       headerTitleStyle: { alignSelf: 'center', top: 0},
       
       
       headerRight: () => (
       <ShoppingCartIcon onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ShoppingCart")}/>)})}/>
       

          <Stack.Screen name = {'ShoppingCart'} component={ShoppingCartNav} options={{headerStyle: {backgroundColor: 'lightblue'}, 
        headerTitle: (
          <View style={styles.logo}>
              <Text style={styles.logo}> Shopping Cart </Text>
          </View>)}}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
    
  );
}
```

ShoppingCartNav

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, SafeAreaView, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { useDimensions } from '@react-native-community/hooks';
import { createStackNavigator, HeaderStyleInterpolators } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import ShoppingCart from '../pages/ArtistPages/ShoppingCart';


const Stack = createStackNavigator();


export default function ShoppingCartNav() {
  console.log(useDimensions());

  return (
 
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name = {'Cart'} component={ShoppingCart} options={{headerStyle: {backgroundColor: 'lightblue'}, 
        headerTitle: (
          <View style={styles.logo}>
              <Text style={styles.logo}> Shopping Cart </Text>
          </View>)}}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>



    
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to accept navigation as props inside your MerchNav component. MerchNav({navigation})

Comment: I ended up wrapping the ShoppingCartIcon inside a TouchableOpacity like so "<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ShoppingCart")}/>  <ShoppingCartIcon />
         </TouchableOpacity> "